# Using cte to swap two columns of a table

Tags: sql-update, common-table-expression

I want to **swap 2nd and 3rd column of one table** using CTE.
I'm working with below query, which keeps throwing an error,
***no such column: cte.comm1
Table - [SalComm] column: ID, Sal, Comm***

```
with CTE as 
    (
      SELECT ID as id1, sal as sal1, comm as comm1 from SalComm
    ) UPDATE SalComm SET sal=cte.comm1, comm=cte.sal1 where ID= cte.id1*
```

Could you please suggest to me the right query?

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you are using SQL Server, or some other database, which supports directly updating common table expressions.  I don't see the point at all of the aliases inside your CTE.  If you want to swap columns values, just use the direct columns names:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, sal, comm
    FROM SalComm
)

UPDATE cte
SET sal = comm, comm = sal;
-- no WHERE clause needed, if you really want to cover the entire table
```

That being said, you could just as easily do the above update on the original table.  Updatable CTEs are more useful when they generate some complex derived results which you intend to use as part of a later update.  That does not appear to be the case here.

Comment: with cte
as 
(
  SELECT ID, sal, comm from SalComm
) 
UPDATE SalComm SET sal=cte.comm, comm=cte.sal;



I got the following error,

no such column: cte.comm
Table - [SalComm] column: ID, Sal, Comm

I was asked this question during an interview to solve using CTE.

Comment: @Shreya That code snippet won't even run AFAIK.  What is the issue here?

Comment: Okay, then a simple question. How do you swap using a cte?

UPDATE SalComm SET sal=comm, comm=sal; ----This works fine so we don't need CTE.

But as my interviewer asked to solve using CTE, writing this post cte, cte statement doesn't  make any sense.

Comment: ... did you actually read my answer, which answers this very question?